# git beta release before live on other subdomain

Tags: git, git-branch

This is how it is now set up:
we have **one bare repository**, we made it like `git init --bare`
then we have many other repositories like:

*johnson.sample dot com*,
*marry.sample dot com*,
*john.sample dot com*

and if we are done with development we push to bare.

After this we go to live server like sample dot com and we pull from bare and all codes are live and ready for use live at sample dot com.

Now the problem is we want ***beta.sample dot com***. So the testing people can see it before we push live.

I taught lets make two bare repositories, where we push from all john.sample dot com, marry.sample dot com etc. to bare.test and from beta.sample dot com we push to other live.bare and then from live sample dot com we pull from live.bare

but the question is: Is this good solution or there are many beter ways to solve this?